# Bundle only supports platforms x64-mingw32 but local is x86_64-linux

Tags: deployment, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5, gemfile

I developed my Rails Application in a Windows environment and I am trying to deploy into Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I am stumbling upon this error:

> Your bundle only supports platforms ["x64-mingw32"] but your local
>   platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-linux"] and there's no compatible match
>   between those two lists.

I think the problem is with gemfile.lock . in addition to seeing strings with 'x64-mingw32' for each gem; I find that there is also this:

> PLATFORMS
>   x64-mingw32

How do I make my application run in a Linux 16.04 LTS Environment?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Gemfile.lock` is restricting the platform your app can run on.
Deploying the app into Linux without the `.lock` file should resolve your issue.

If you have any Windows-specific gems in your `Gemfile`, its better to move them to a dedicated block:

```ruby
# Gemfile

platform :mswin, :mingw, :x64_mingw do
  gem "tzinfo-data"
  gem "win32_api"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano requires the Gemfile.lock file for deployment. Bundler is the one that is causing this but according to their Github it is intented behaviour to make your app compatible with different platforms.

In order for this to work - as of 1.13, you could run `bundle lock --add-platform ruby` on Windows to add the ruby platform to your lockfile ahead of time.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/4620)